# can't exec " java " no such file or directory at ./fastqc line 307

Tags: java, ubuntu

When I want to install fastqc file in Ubuntu, I face this error: can't exec " java " no such file or directory at ./fastqc line 307
I tried to install Java with this command " sudo apt install java-common" but it doesn't work
I would be happy if you help me with this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Wrong package name.
apt-cache search '^openjdk' 
will show you what you need. E.g. sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install JRE or JDK. Check [this page](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-jre#2-installing-openjdk-jre).